# Gradle dependencyResolutionManagement brokes flutter project dependency

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I started use dependencyResolutionManagement in my settings.gradle file and it helps me with some problems but it hides my flutter Activity.

How to fix my problem and use `dependencyResolutionManagement` and flutter dependency?

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    include ':app',
            ':core',
    
    rootProject.name = "MyApp"
    
    setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
    evaluate(new File(
            rootProject.projectDir,
            'flutter_app/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
    ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried `repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)` and it helps me